# Image upload from browser to amazon S3 using perl

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I want to upload image from browser to amazon s3 bucket using perl. I have found some link to save the image to our server then migrate to amazon s3 bucket.I want to know that is there any option to directly upload image ?

Answer (score 0):

I Googled "browser upload to Amazon S3". The first result was this link - [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST (AWS Signature Version 2)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html). The actual details are on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html). Basically, you set the form's action to the URL of your S3 bucket and set all of the authentication stuff in the forms' hidden fields.

But wouldn't you be worried that a user could incur huge S3 charges on your behalf?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and the AWS.S3 class would be a good bet if you want to do that from a browser.

Comment: I didn't mean from client side upload, how to upload the image from server side once we get the binary image in perl script.